# Replace space for %20 in Spring with UriCompnentsBuilder

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've got a method that takes some parameters and forms a URI from them in order to access our client REST service. It may occur of one of these parameters be a space. The problem is that UriComponentsBuilder.pathSegment ignores space. So, let say, `'v1', ' ', 'v2'`... would form the URI `.../v1/v2` instead of `/v1/%20/v2`. If I pass `%20` directly to pathSegment, it will replace by %2520. This is my function

```
 private String getJsonStringFromDetranRestParams(String url, String... params) {

    URI targetUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url).pathSegment(params).build().encode().toUri();
    String json = restTemplate.getForObject(targetUrl, String.class);

    return json;
}
```

Is there any kind of 'escape character' to the function so it will see `%20` as a valid string instead of a special string. I'm looking for a `\\` Java equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `build()` to return it as String, space will be ignored in `pathSegment` you have to pass `%20`

```
String targetUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://localhost:8080").pathSegment("v1","%20","v2").build().toUriString();
System.out.println(targetUrl);  //http://localhost:8080/v1/%20/v2
```

or use `build(true)` to encode

```
 URI targetUrl = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://localhost:8080").pathSegment("v1","%20","v2").build(true).toUri();
System.out.println(targetUrl); ////http://localhost:8080/v1/%20/v2
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to do this with UriComponentsBuilder is as follows:

```
UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://localhost:8080").encode().build().toUri()
```